# Is it safe to access a variable from the main thread after it was written to by another thread and after that thread was joined?

Tags: c++

Is this thread-safe?

```
int x = 0;
std::thread([&]{ x = 1; }).join();
std::cout << x;
```

Variable x is accessed from two threads without using atomics or locks. However, the call to  `join()` forces the accesses to x to be sequential.

Is a memory barrier required here?

Comment: no data race = no need for that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, ***that particular*** code snippet is thread safe; barriers or locks are not required.

This is the timeline of events with respect to your code:

```
thread 1 
--------
   |
  int x = 0;
  (write 0 to x)
   |
  std::thread                thread 2
  (start thread 2) --------> --------
   |                            |
  join();                      x = 1;
  (thread 1 suspended)         (write 1 to x)
   .                            |
   .                           thread 2 returns
   .                            |
  (thread 1 resumes) <-------   x
   |
  std::cout << x;
  (read from x)
   |
  thread 1 returns
   |
   x
```

As you can see, at no point is `x` being accessed by more than one thread. In fact, the use of `join()` *effectively makes all accesses to* `x` *happen in sequential order*, as you've surmised. The `join()` provides the synchronization in lieu of the synchronization you get from locks.

Basically, what you have is an example of how you can have multithreading with zero concurrency.

Of course, this is true only because of the call to `join()`, which happens immediately after you create the thread in the code snippet you provide. If you instead had something like this:

```
int x = 0;
std::thread t([&]{ x = 1; });
std::cout << x;
t.join(); // Move join() call here
```

The timeline instead may look like this:

```
thread 1 
--------
   |
  int x = 0;
  (write 0 to x)
   |
  std::thread                thread 2
  (start thread 2) --------> --------
   |                            |
  std::cout << x;              x = 1;
  (read from x)                (write 1 to x)    <-- PROBLEM!
   |                            |
  join();                       |
  (thread 1 suspended)          |
   .                            |
   .                           thread 2 returns
   .                            |
  (thread 1 resumes) <-------   x
   |
  thread 1 returns
   |
   x
```

Changing the order of `join()` in this manner will introduce a race.

Comment: That's a very comprehensive way of saying 'Yes'.

Comment: I think I'm going to use that diagram style for posting about threads from now on.

Comment: unless join() has some special guarantee, the main thread could use the cached value of x even after the join() and printing the old result, no?

Comment: @mitchnull: You're thinking at too low-level of abstraction. As far as C++ is concerned, there's only one `x` variable, and both threads read and/or write to it (the second thread of course does it through a reference). The variable `x` may actually be in fact two copies on separate processors, but it's the processor's job to ensure changes are propagated through all copies (e.g. see the [MESI protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)). Such implementation details, however, is irrelevant to the language.